# React: fetch updated data from server without refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

Suppose my React component structure looks as follows:

```
App
|-PostList
|-CreatePost
```

In PostList component I populate my state by fetching data from a server like:

```js
...
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPosts() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_API}/posts`)
        await setPosts(res.data)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
    fetchPosts()
  }, []);
```

And render those posts. Again, in my CreatePost component I create a new post and sent those data to the server like this:

```js
...
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post(`${BACKEND_API}/posts/create`, { title });
    setTitle('')
  };
...
```

Now there the problem arise. I can't see my new post without refreshing the page. I try to solve this problem like lifting state up in the App component and pass the `setPosts` handler to the CreatePost component. Because I was thinking to update my posts state again inside the `submitHandler` like this:

```js
    async function refreshPosts(setPosts) {
      const res = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_API}/posts`)
      await setPosts(res.data)
    }
```

I was confused is it the corrent way? As I heard lifting state up is not a good decision. Is there any better solution? I was trying to avoid any state management lib. Which come with a lot of extra work for this simple problem.

Comment: while sending data to the server have you added a new post to your state that is storing posts? because I am not seeing in `submitHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lifting state up is a good decision until you're not drilling props for children that are 3-4 level deep.

I recommend putting it in a container component (Post) that passes props to `PostList` and `CreatePost` though. In the future, you might have more components in your App. Then, other future components might `re-render` unnecessarily.

```
App
|-Post // put all your state and handlers regarding Post here
 |-PostList // use this just as plain view, just shows the list of the post
 |-CreatePost // use this just as plain view, just form to create a post
|-FutureComponent // handles it own state, doesn't re-render when post change
|-FutureMoreComponent // handles it own state,, doesn't re-render when post change
```

In the above structures, your `FutureComponent` and `FutureMoreComponent` won't re-render if your `Post` re-renders because `Post` is a self-contained component.

Your component structure might look something like this then

PostList.js

```
<PostList posts={postsStateFromPostComponent} />
```

CreatePost.js

```
<CreatePost onSubmit={apiThatCreatesANewPost} />
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. What I understand is "Wrap my components which need/update post state". I will accept your answer 23 hours later as I haven't enough repo to upvote your answer :) . Let see what the other said. Thanks for your response @Prateek Thapa